# How to Send keys in a Game?

Tags: sendkeys

Okay let me get this straight. I would like to send two keys nonstop (Q and R) in a game. Something like Press Q, Wait a second, Press R, Wait a second, over and over again. How would you guys do that ? Thank you in advance
-Alex

Comment: Similarly, like you can write "Hello World" in [many different ways](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/234075/what-is-your-best-programmer-joke?page=3&tab=votes#answer-939409), you can also do this in a variety of ways. The question does not have a specific programming problem, so it's basically off-topic.

Comment: In the game itself, pressing Q and R actually do something. But when I run the vbs file, nothing happens, but if I press Enter, which enables the chat in the game, then I see it's typing qrqrqrqr, but that's only the chat. Q and R actually has to do something in the game, but nothing happens

Comment: Perhaps you should ask in [Arqade](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/), In less of course you are going to program this your self.. you have a language of choice and you can supply some sample code with the exact issue you are having. otherwise this seems off topic.